# Generate stateless client-side forms from server-side Models?

Tags: python, ruby, web-applications, ember.js, code-generation

#### Client-side (example)

JavaScript framework: Ember.js, AngularJS or KnockoutJS

#### Server-side (example)

Python-based: Flask, web2py, Django; or Ruby-based: Rails, Ramaze, Sinatra

---

**Are there any open-source server-side libraries which can take database schemas (Models); and generate—MVVM or MVC—client-side forms?**

Specifically looking for code generation of:

- JSON HTTP RESTful API endpoints
- Form validation with callbacks in stateless JavaScript

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight: You want to have on the client side an equivalent of your model in the server side? Just the data or it should have an API on the server to receive calls to save, call a model method, create a new model, and stuff?

Comment: Pretty much. I mean it's pretty easy to do manually, but it takes a while to code in; and there is a lot of double-typing (attributes and validation).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold is an example.

Comment: I don't believe this is what I am looking for. If it is, can you include some sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no experience in any of these libraries they do seem to exist:

http://activescaffold.com/ (Ruby on Rails based) 
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Yeoman-and-Express (Express is a Node.js backend)

While (arguably) a bit more work you can also do it in the Java Spring framework:
http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/scaffoldingtutorial/scaffolding.html (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0id0xzuYBA)

[Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) and [Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/) (with http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Play) also seem to be capable of this.

I would however carefully weigh the pros and cons of such an approach. Apart from the absolute basics the code generation methods are almost always more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

This is one seems more like something you would be searching for:
http://blog.ricodigo.com/blog/2012/10/14/announcing-the-release-of-angularjs-scaffold/

It uses Ruby on the server side and scaffolds an app with angularjs, bootstrap and font-awesome on the client side.

Here is the code: https://github.com/patcito/angularjs_scaffold